# Books that every undergraduate should read

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, big-list

Reference requests are common. However, I wish to make this a list of books which every undergraduate, majoring in mathematics should own or at least read. It may be a bit subjective.

Please include 1 book per answer. If there is any additional (or alternate) recommendation by you or some other person for the same topic please include it in the comments.

Comment: Cider with Rosie, by Laurie Lee. I read this during my undergrad, and found it rather enjoyable!

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/761/undergraduate-level-math-books Also, real analysis courses must always use Rudin!

Comment: @user1729 : ) ${}{}{}$

Comment: I don't think such books exist.

Comment: Every undergraduate should own the course catalog.

Comment: "a list of books which every undergraduate should own or at least read". Two clarifications are required: 1) Math books, or any-subject books? 2) math-major undergraduates, or all undergraduates?

Comment: @AakashM Mathematics texts for undergraduates, majoring in mathematics.The website is math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Chris: The website is maths.stackexchange.com and so you should make your questions precise. Mathematicians like precision!

Comment: @Chris thanks. Unfortunately it's been amply demonstrated that simply *naming* a site doesn't automatically prevent off-topic questions being asked; hence my request for clarification.

Comment: It got closed as not a real question but I voted as "not constructive" since everyone has their own opinion.

Answer (score 2):

[Aigner and Ziegler, *Proofs from The Book*.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3642008550) Hours of fun.

Answer (score 0):

A bit clichéd, but...

[**Principles of Mathematical Analysis**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/007054235X) by Walter Rudin